# Getting null value in Jquery in partial view

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using Jquery in partial view for passing data to controller. Here is my partial view code:

```
    @model List<Apostille.Models.Cart>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("MinusQuantity", "Cart", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(
                    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(columnName: "country_name", header: "Country Name"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "state_name", header: "State Name"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "document_title", header: "Document Title"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "document_name", header: "Document Name"),
            grid.Column(header: "Document Quantity", format: @<div><button onclick="minus(@item.order_id,@item.number_of_document)" data-type="minus" class="btn btn-danger btn-number" data-field="number_of_document"><b>-</b></button> <span style="margin-left: 18%">@Html.Raw(@item.number_of_document)</span> <button onclick="plus(@item.order_id,@item.number_of_document)" data-type="plus" class="btn btn-success btn-number" data-field="number_of_document", style="float:right"><b>+</b></button></div>),
            grid.Column(columnName: "first_doc_price", header: "First Doc Price"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "addition_doc_price", header: "Additional Doc Price"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "extra_total", header: "Addtional Doc Total"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "total", header: "Final Total")
            //grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "_EditCartPartial", new { @id = "send id here" }))
   ))
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        alert("DOM loaded!");

        function minus(orderId, qty) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MinusQuantity", "Cart")',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { 'OrderId': orderId, 'Quantity': qty },
                sucess: function (data) {

                }
            })
        }
    });
    //alert("this script tag is executing properly!");

    function plus(orderId, qty) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PlusQuantity", "Cart")',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { 'OrderId': orderId, 'Quantity': qty },
            sucess: function (data) {

            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

I can call jquery successfully, but I am getting null value in orderid and qty, when i click button for webgrid.

I read somewhere that jquery doesn't work in partial view, so i tried to put jquery in index.cshtml, but still I got null value for both of this.

However if I move webgrid to index.html, jquery working all fine.

What could be the possible reason, that jquery not working in partial view? what should I do to overcome this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parseInt

```
function minus(orderId, qty) {
            var ordId = parseInt(orderId);
            var quant = parseInt(qty);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MinusQuantity", "Cart")',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { 'OrderId': ordId , 'Quantity': quant},
                sucess: function (data) {

                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer